# Deshabilitar un input cuando mi otro input tenga un valor cualquiera

Tags: html, jquery

Actualmente de me encuentro en la siguiente situación en `JavaScript`, me gustaría que cuando mi campo de **#q3** tenga un valor radom, se deshabilite mi campo **#q2** igual de linea única.

Adjunto una captura de pantalla de mi código que no funciona al campo **q3** le meto cualquier dato ya sea letras o números y **q2** no se deshabilita.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Field3").on("change", function() {
        if (parseInt($("#Field3").val()) === 0) {
            $("#Field2").prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $("#Field2").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: La pregunta se edita yendo a [edit]. Abajo sólo van los intentos de respuesta (como el mío) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ojo!** En el código `jQuery` buscas el `id` del campo **Field2** pero en el screenshot parece que el `id` es **q2**, lo mismo para **Field3** y **q3**. Ambos `id` deben ser coherentes en `HTML` y `jQuery`.

Adicionalmente, en la validación estás "parseando" a entero el `value` del campo y estás comparando que sea igual a cero y esto no va a ser correcto: `parseInt($("#Field3").val()) === 0`. En su lugar podrías validar que el campo esté o no vacío.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Field3").on("input", function() {
        if ($("#Field3").val() === '') {
            $("#Field2").prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $("#Field2").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Field2" />
<input id="Field3" />
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio de mucho en verdad

Comment: solo que por lo que veo , se deshabilita el campo cuando doy click fuera del campo , tendria que poner algun evento que no sea Onchange para que al momento de poner el 1 solito el campo se deshabilite ????

Comment: Con el evento `oninput` lo solucionas. Acabo de editar mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba añadiendo o retirando el atributo `disabled` del elemento.

Para deshabilitar:

```
$('#Field2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Para habilitar:

```
$('#Field2').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: ya se los agregue pero cunado le meto un valor al #q3 no me deshabilita el #q2

Comment: @JUANCARLOSURBANROMERO por favor ve a editar tu pregunta y **añade** lo que intentaste a partir de esta respuesta, junto con el problema (qué dato estás metiendo en q3)